# Assembler and C++ relation

Tags: c++, assembly

Is there any tutorial or explanation anywhere on how C++ objects translate into assembler instructions moving data between registers...

I don't really understand how we are manipulating object in higher level languages where in Assembler you're essentially moving data between registers?  Plus doing some basic operations on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I will use IA-32 assembly for samples.

Typically, each object is a structure residing block of memory allocated either on heap (via `new` call) or on stacK (basically, by moving `esp` to reserve memory for it). After memory is allocated, pointer is passed to object constructor for initialization (note that ctor can be inlined, this way no `call` is made).

Usually, each object having virtual methods has a pointer a table of virtual methods (usually called VMT or [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vtable) which stores pointers to functions. When you are calling virtual method, address of this method is got and it is called. Code looks like this

```
mov ecx, [this]
mov ebx, vtable
push [arg2]
push [arg1]
call [ebx + OFFSET_foo] ; this->foo(arg1, arg2);
```

Note that in this sample I've shown that `this` is passed via ecx and args are passed via stack in right-to-left order. This is [`thiscall` convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#thiscall), used in VC++ by default, e.g. Other compilers may employ other conventions, as it is shown in article linked.

For non-virtual calls no need for table lookup. So code looks like

```
 mov ecx, [this]
 push [args]
 push [arg1]
 call bar   ; this->bar(arg1, arg2)
```

This is why non-virtual methods can be executed a bit faster - its address is well known, so compiler can start decoding their code before encountering `call` opcode.

In some calling conventions (e.g. `fastcall`) arguments are passed via registers which can be faster in some cases.

In most calling conventions result iss returned via `eax` register if it fits this registers, via FPU stack, if this is floating point or via stack otherwise.

If you want to learn more about translating C++ code to assembly, I'd recommend to

- try to make your compiler generate assembly listing during compilation (usually -S key; it can be set in VC++ project settings as well);
- try to disassemble code e.g. using excellent IDA disassembler. There's [free version](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idadownfreeware.htm) of it. It helps a lot by providing symbolic names for local variables, recognizing library functions etc.

Good luck!